# Подключение к БД и Singleton. Как лучше?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

Если класс подключения к БД в себе имеет функцию запроса и в конце имеет закрытие подключения, то имеет ли смысл в данной ситуации делать из него Singleton?
И правильно ли вообще реализовывать в одном классе подключение, запрос и закрытие подключения? Как вариант, возможно, close() вывести в отдельную функцию и вызывать по мере необходимости, а не закрывать каждый раз подключение после каждого запроса?

Comment: @--A Синглтоны не нужны. Вообще. Честно. Нужен один экземпляр - пользуйтесь одним экземпляром, храните в реестре или контейнере.

> И правильно ли вообще реализовывать в одном классе подключение, запрос и закрытие подключения?

Да. Ваш класс подразумевает собой одно соединение с базой данных. Его нужно открыть, закрыть, спустить в него тонну запросов и получить от него тонну ответов.

> Как вариант, возможно, close() вывести в отдельную функцию и вызывать по мере необходимости, а не закрывать каждый раз подключение после каждого запроса?

Не то что возможно, обязательно.

Comment: Понятный ответ, спасибо.
При загрузки страницы подключаются разные модули, которые обращаются к одной базе каждый со своими запросами и получается создается несколько копий класса подключения к БД. Отсюда и вопросы - закрывать подключение сразу после каждого(!) запроса или закрывать на в конце выполнения скрипта, чтобы все успели выполнить запросы(равносильно не закрытию вообще, так как при окончании выполнения скрипта все само закрывается) или же вариант реализовать Singleton и отдавать один единственный экземпляр всем?
С реестрами и контейнерами не сталкивался. Можно поподробней, пожалуйста

Comment: "храните в реестре" - реестр - частный случай синглтона так то

Answer (score 2):

Использовать синглетон для для подключения к базе данных нет надобности:

1. На уровне драйвера, устанавливающего связь с СУБД не осуществляется повторной установки соединения, если уже имеется соединение с такими же параметрами. Вместо этого возвращается уже существующее соединение.
2. Соединение имеет смысл закрывать, если вы ожидаете медленный запрос, который почему-то будет обрабатываться PHP. Например, выполнили запрос к базе данных и стали отдавать пользователю 4Гб файла. Занятое соединение не будет участвовать в обработке других запросов и если в текущем скрипте больше не ожидается соединений, имеет смысл закрыть соединение с базой данных до того, как пользователь принялся долго и упорно выкачивать объемные данные. Если ваш скрипт отрабатывает несколько микросекунд - в явном закрытии соединений нет надобности - они будут автоматически закрыты после выполнения скрипта.